# Syncing jQuery background and element animation

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, background-position

I have illustrated my problem in the following Fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/6CTMs/

The background of the `wrapper` is an image with a white hole in the middle. This hole is then covered by the `block` element.

Now I want to animate the background and the block moving up. I'm simultaneously animating the background position (via the included background position animation plugin) and the `top` attribute of the `block` element.

However, at least on my Chrome 21.0.1180.79 on Win7, these two animations are not entirely in sync. It seems every other frame of animation, a white band (revealing a one-pixel high slice of the hole underneath) shows at the bottom, and every other frame it doesn't.

How can I avoid this?

Including the background image in a child element and only animating the top attribute of that is not an option in my case. I also can't make the element one pixel taller or any 'hack' like that - the dimensions and animations need to be precise.

As a sidenote, I think that this issue may perhaps be related to [an earlier question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12078635/951402), which never fully got resolved.

**EDIT:** I've forked the Fiddle here; http://jsfiddle.net/3r26H/1/ Seems to work but it looks like it leaves one pixel off at the end of the animation. I also don't know if this creates new issues in non-Webkit browsers. How kosher is this solution?

Comment: In perfect sync when testing on **Firefox 14.0.1**.

Comment: Thanks Abody97! Perhaps this is a Webkit-only issue then? Interesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this thread : [JQuery synchronous animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594077/jquery-synchronous-animation) it's impossible to sync two animations in JQuery. What you can do through, is animate the whole thing "by hand", using `requestAnimationFrame` and making the right computations at each frame so that both elements are sync.

Comment: I was able to make this Fiddle using that logic and the step function from the answer to the question I linked, and it seems to work on my Chrome apart from the fact that the animation leaves 1 pixel off once it's finished; http://jsfiddle.net/3r26H/1/ -- any idea on how cross-browser reliable this effect is?

Comment: it does not seem to work for me :/ (Mac OS X Lion - Chrome & Firefox). So for your question I would say it's not reliable :) I'm working on another fiddle to show you how I would have done it (and if what I thought at first is really a good solution :D )

Comment: Looks cool, and works for me too! What's the backwards compatibility of this solution?

Comment: Also, setting the animation speed seems a bit mystifying to me; 20000 milliseconds is my set time. How do I vary that with your solution?

Comment: If by "backward compatibility" you mean if this code will work on older browser : it should work but I haven't tested it :/ 

You should take a look here if you want a better polyfill for the requestAnimFrame function : http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: If the tech was in nightlies and dev builds in 2011, I'm guessing `requestAnimationFrame` isn't old enough to be the sole solution. But then again, with an old browser I'm okay with the 1 pixel error. I'll tinker around with `requestAnimationFrame` support detection to provide the original jQuery fallback.