# Start CSS3 animation using Javascript with onclick event

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, dom-events, css-animations

I'm working on a webapp that uses CSS3 animations for some nice effects, but I can't figure out to activate them with an `onclick` event.

this is the CSS3 Animation: (The name of the DIV this is added to is `#smspopup`)

```
#smspopup {    
-webkit-animation: move-sms 1.5s 1;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

And this is my Javascript where I just can't figure out what I need to get it going

```
function cancel_sms() 
{
    halte.style.opacity = 1;
    document.getElementById('smspopup').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('up').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

And another thing I want to do is delay the functions 1.5 seconds until the animation is finished. Anyone any idea?

Comment: [**This question** might help.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062818/how-to-combine-jquery-animate-with-css3-properties-without-using-css-transitions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Starting the animation**

Start by using a class instead of an ID.  Change the CSS to this:

```
.smspopup {    
    -webkit-animation: move-sms 1.5s 1;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

And add `class=smspopup` to the `smspopup` element.

Next, inside the handler (`cancel_sms`?), just add the class to the element to begin the animation:

```
document.getElementById('smspopup').className = 'smspopup';
```

**Animation end callback**

For the second question (targeting the end of the animation), there are two options:

1. Attach a callback to the *transitionEnd* event.  The only problem with this is that you need to listen to vendor-specific events:

   `myDiv.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', callback);`
2. Use a regular timeout.  The problem with this is that the timing won't be perfect (but maybe close enough).

   `setTimeout(callback, 1500);`

Comment: Ok, no problem, what I was currently trying is this:
_italic_document.getElementById('smspopup').-webkit-animation('move-sms 1.5s 1 forwards;');_
Any idea where I went wrong here?

Comment: @IanBauters to add CSS properties directly, you'd use this:  *document.getElementById('smspopup').style["-webkit-animation"] = 'move-sms 1.5s 1 forwards';*

Comment: Great! thanks, you din't happen to know how you reset the animation with webkitAnimationEnd?