# Triggering CSS3 animation with JQuery hover not working

Tags: jquery, animation, css

I'm trying to make some icons jump on hover using CSS3 and Jquery. The bounce animation is attached to the `.bounce` class in a stylesheet; to handle the hover, I told Jquery to add and remove the `bounce` class when the mouse enters and leaves the image's parent element respectively. While the Jquery is working as expected, the animation is not, and I'm not sure why.

[Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/fyTpV/) I appreciate the help.

Comment: if you want further more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062818/how-to-combine-jquery-animate-with-css3-properties-without-using-css-transitions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the animation-duration:

```
.bounce {    
    // this is the shorthand definition
    -webkit-animation: bounce 1s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation: bounce 1s ease infinite;
    -o-animation: bounce 1s ease infinite;
    animation: bounce 1s ease infinite;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fyTpV/2/

Comment: he's using someone elses css I think. The class Animated has those values in it. It just need to be put on the elem to animate.

Comment: That did it! Thanks a lot. I'd assumed that the css sheet generated for me would have the timing already built into it. I've never used CSS3 animations before, so I didn't even think to check that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the animated class. Here's the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fyTpV/3/ add the class to the elem you wish to animate or in your add class add the animated class as well.