# transform: rotateX in jquery .animate function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flip

I am trying to perform a flip effect using CSS.
How can I get -

`transform: perspective(1200px) rotateX(0deg)`

from

`transform: perspective(1200px) rotateX(90deg)`

using jQuery's `.animate()` function?

I've tried to do with jQuery 2D Transformation Plugin but no success.

Comment: Just add a custom CSS Hook and you're ready to go. Though, I don't know of any standard to pass more than one argument to it.

Comment: You could try the answer here, you would just need to modify it to accept two arguments. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062818/how-to-combine-jquery-animate-with-css3-properties-without-using-css-transitions

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/ERRmd/

Answer (score 1):

Use native CSS. Something like this:

```
.panel {
    transform: perspective(1200px) rotateX(0deg);
    transition: transform 0.5s linear;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s linear;
}
.panel.flip {
    transform: perspective(1200px) rotateX(90deg);
}
```

Then just toggle the class.

Comment: Thank this helped, but it works only in Firefox, I tried to rewrite code in such way... will put my code in answer, but it doesn`t help me...flip efect works only in Firefox... how can i make it multibrowser?

Comment: It also works in IE10. To make it work in Chrome, add `-webkit-transform` and change the `-webkit-transition` to affect `-webkit-transform`.